# Windows Server TCP sockets random disconnect: how to reproduce?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hardware, tcp, ethernet

We rented 10 Windows servers from a large provider in Europe. They all work as expected. One server suddenly crashed and customer care found that both disks were broken. They replaced disks and also memory (they run a test and found a faulty DIMM).

After this, server was reinstalled from scratch with Windows 2008 server R2.

Now we're experiencing random TCP sockets disconnection in our software (it's a server software that handles ~200 realtime TCP connections). We made a lot of tests but we cannot reproduce the problem which is totally random.

Sometimes, also VNC, SSH, RDP connections drop, so it's not related to our software.

I reinstalled again Windows 2008 and as the first thing I downloaded Firefox... downloaded stopped due to disconnection.

It seems definitely an hardware issue.

All other servers are running same SO on same hardware. We never had problems.

How can I reproduce this issue to show the provider that there is an hardware problem? Is there some specific Windows based test suite for network problems?

I'm open to suggestions.

**Update 1**

Wireshark capture shows that server is suddenly sending a RST,ACK packet.
There are a lot of retransmissions and some packets before RST there is such a packet:

```
[TCP ACKed unseen segment] https > 60226 [ACK] Seq=42906 Ack=79 Win=253 Len=0 SLE=27 SRE=53 443 60226
```

**Update 2**

NIC adapter is a Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller. Driver is rt64win7.sys from Realtek, version 7.065.1025.2012. It's the one supplied with the preinstalled server for every customer. It works correctly with the very same drivers on other servers.

**Update 3**

I installed latest version of Wireshark. I run `wget -m --limit-rate 1000 somesite` to generate some requests with TCP traffic.

There are a lot of warnings in Wireshark capture. Window Full, ZeroWindow. I tried different sites with wget and warnings always appears. Could this be our problem?

```
11  0.569100000 xx.xx.xxx.216 xx.xxx.xxx.80 TCP 554 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
12  0.569356000 xx.xx.xxx.216 xx.xxx.xxx.80 TCP 554 [TCP Window Full] [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
13  0.569376000 xx.xxx.xxx.80 xx.xx.xxx.216 TCP 54  58572 > http [ACK] Seq=266 Ack=1828 Win=1000 Len=0
14  0.655205000 xx.xx.xxx.216 xx.xxx.xxx.80 TCP 554 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
15  0.655443000 xx.xx.xxx.216 xx.xxx.xxx.80 TCP 554 [TCP Window Full] [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
16  0.655457000 xx.xxx.xxx.80 xx.xx.xxx.216 TCP 54  58572 > http [ACK] Seq=266 Ack=2828 Win=1000 Len=0
17  0.741237000 xx.xx.xxx.216 xx.xxx.xxx.80 TCP 554 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
18  0.741498000 xx.xx.xxx.216 xx.xxx.xxx.80 TCP 554 [TCP Window Full] [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
19  0.741516000 xx.xxx.xxx.80 xx.xx.xxx.216 TCP 54  [TCP ZeroWindow] 58572 > http [ACK] Seq=266 Ack=3828 Win=0 Len=0
20  1.060906000 xx.xxx.xxx.80 xx.xx.xxx.216 TCP 54  [TCP Window Update] 58572 > http [ACK] Seq=266 Ack=3828 Win=1000 Len=0
21  1.146737000 xx.xx.xxx.216 xx.xxx.xxx.80 TCP 554 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
22  1.146993000 xx.xx.xxx.216 xx.xxx.xxx.80 TCP 554 [TCP Window Full] [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
23  1.147007000 xx.xxx.xxx.80 xx.xx.xxx.216 TCP 54  [TCP ZeroWindow] 58572 > http [ACK] Seq=266 Ack=4828 Win=0 Len=0
24  1.634966000 xx.xx.xxx.216 xx.xxx.xxx.80 TCP 60  [TCP Keep-Alive] http > 58572 [ACK] Seq=4827 Ack=266 Win=15616 Len=0
25  1.634981000 xx.xxx.xxx.80 xx.xx.xxx.216 TCP 54  [TCP ZeroWindow] 58572 > http [ACK] Seq=266 Ack=4828 Win=0 Len=0
```

**Update 4**

I spotted some weird behaviour in Wireshark capture.

```
44176   1183.719018000  xx.xxx.xxx.80   xx.x.xxx.88 TCP 1506    [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
44177   1183.724259000  xx.x.xxx.88 xx.xxx.xxx.80   TCP 78  [TCP Dup ACK 44174#1] 57852 > http [ACK] Seq=94 Ack=868148 Win=175872 Len=0 TSval=190130437 TSecr=8617727 SLE=869588 SRE=871028
44178   1183.724297000  xx.xxx.xxx.80   xx.x.xxx.88 TCP 1506    [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
44179   1183.725337000  xx.x.xxx.88 xx.xxx.xxx.80   TCP 78  [TCP Dup ACK 44174#2] 57852 > http [ACK] Seq=94 Ack=868148 Win=175872 Len=0 TSval=190130437 TSecr=8617727 SLE=869588 SRE=872468
44180   1183.725353000  xx.xxx.xxx.80   xx.x.xxx.88 TCP 1506    [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
44181   1183.753811000  xx.x.xxx.88 xx.xxx.xxx.80   TCP 86  [TCP Dup ACK 44174#3] 57852 > http [ACK] Seq=94 Ack=868148 Win=175872 Len=0 TSval=190130445 TSecr=8617727 SLE=873908 SRE=875348 SLE=869588 SRE=872468
44182   1183.753838000  xx.xxx.xxx.80   xx.x.xxx.88 TCP 1506    [TCP Fast Retransmission] [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
44183   1183.758173000  xx.x.xxx.88 xx.xxx.xxx.80   TCP 86  [TCP Dup ACK 44174#4] 57852 > http [ACK] Seq=94 Ack=868148 Win=175872 Len=0 TSval=190130447 TSecr=8617727 SLE=873908 SRE=876788 SLE=869588 SRE=872468
44184   1183.768334000  xx.x.xxx.88 xx.xxx.xxx.80   TCP 86  [TCP Dup ACK 44174#5] 57852 > http [ACK] Seq=94 Ack=868148 Win=175872 Len=0 TSval=190130449 TSecr=8617727 SLE=873908 SRE=878228 SLE=869588 SRE=872468
44185   1183.770232000  xx.x.xxx.88 xx.xxx.xxx.80   TCP 86  [TCP Dup ACK 44174#6] 57852 > http [ACK] Seq=94 Ack=868148 Win=175872 Len=0 TSval=190130449 TSecr=8617727 SLE=873908 SRE=879668 SLE=869588 SRE=872468
44186   1183.773544000  xx.x.xxx.88 xx.xxx.xxx.80   TCP 86  [TCP Dup ACK 44174#7] 57852 > http [ACK] Seq=94 Ack=868148 Win=175872 Len=0 TSval=190130450 TSecr=8617727 SLE=873908 SRE=881108 SLE=869588 SRE=872468
44187   1183.784085000  xx.x.xxx.88 xx.xxx.xxx.80   TCP 86  [TCP Dup ACK 44174#8] 57852 > http [ACK] Seq=94 Ack=868148 Win=175872 Len=0 TSval=190130452 TSecr=8617727 SLE=873908 SRE=882548 SLE=869588 SRE=872468
44188   1183.784097000  xx.xxx.xxx.80   xx.x.xxx.88 TCP 101 [TCP Retransmission] [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
44189   1183.789043000  xx.x.xxx.88 xx.xxx.xxx.80   TCP 86  [TCP Dup ACK 44174#9] 57852 > http [ACK] Seq=94 Ack=868148 Win=175872 Len=0 TSval=190130453 TSecr=8617727 SLE=873908 SRE=883988 SLE=869588 SRE=872468
44190   1183.789056000  xx.xxx.xxx.80   xx.x.xxx.88 TCP 1471    [TCP Retransmission] [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
44191   1183.793926000  xx.x.xxx.88 xx.xxx.xxx.80   TCP 94  [TCP Dup ACK 44174#10] 57852 > http [ACK] Seq=94 Ack=868148 Win=175872 Len=0 TSval=190130454 TSecr=8617727 SLE=895508 SRE=896948 SLE=873908 SRE=883988 SLE=869588 SRE=872468
44192   1183.793939000  xx.xxx.xxx.80   xx.x.xxx.88 TCP 1506    [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
44193   1183.800204000  xx.x.xxx.88 xx.xxx.xxx.80   TCP 94  [TCP Dup ACK 44174#11] 57852 > http [ACK] Seq=94 Ack=868148 Win=175872 Len=0 TSval=190130457 TSecr=8617727 SLE=895508 SRE=898388 SLE=873908 SRE=883988 SLE=869588 SRE=872468
44194   1183.800217000  xx.xxx.xxx.80   xx.x.xxx.88 TCP 1506    [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
44195   1183.803615000  xx.x.xxx.88 xx.xxx.xxx.80   TCP 94  [TCP Dup ACK 44174#12] 57852 > http [ACK] Seq=94 Ack=868148 Win=175872 Len=0 TSval=190130457 TSecr=8617727 SLE=895508 SRE=899828 SLE=873908 SRE=883988 SLE=869588 SRE=872468
44196   1183.803640000  xx.xxx.xxx.80   xx.x.xxx.88 TCP 1506    [TCP Retransmission] [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
44197   1183.803654000  xx.xxx.xxx.80   xx.x.xxx.88 TCP 1506    [TCP Retransmission] [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
44198   1183.803660000  xx.xxx.xxx.80   xx.x.xxx.88 TCP 1506    [TCP Retransmission] [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
44199   1183.803665000  xx.xxx.xxx.80   xx.x.xxx.88 TCP 1506    [TCP Retransmission] [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
.. a lot of these
```

There is 1 second of errors. I had 2 connections and none fall down. Retransmissions saved the connections.

I will go to the provider showing all these errors. I hope to convince them.

Comment: Are you able to say what make/model of NIC and of the server it is? Also, which driver/firmware/teaming software you're using?

Comment: Hardware is Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller. Driver is rt64win7.sys from Realtek, version 7.065.1025.2012. It's the one supplied with the preinstalled server for every customer.

Comment: It looks like driver 7.078 is available. Unfortunately, there's nothing to say if your issue is a known problem with that driver. http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3

Answer (score 2):

Two things I would do are: use the [Realtek diagnostics](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) to check for a hardware issue.
And: setup [performance counter logging](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722414.aspx) on the interface - specifically look at the following counters:

Network Interface\Packets Outbound Errors
Network Interface\Packets Received Errors
TCPv4\Connection Failures
TCPv4\Connections Reset

This should help record the issue you're seeing, and can be provided to your host to show the issues you're having. Also - setup the same performance counter logging on some healthy servers for comparison.

Comment: I installed Realtek diagnostics on server. They report no errors. I created perfomance counter logging as you suggested. I'll leave them running with some client making connections and tomorrow we'll see.

Comment: No errors were logged by performance counter. I downloaded 10000+ files with no errors.

Comment: Were there any dropped connections during that time?

Comment: No dropped connections but TCP retransmissions and other warnings. I had only 2 connections with low traffic. I suspect that when traffic is higher, connections would drop.

Answer (score 1):

You could use packet capture software such as wireshark to look at what is going on.

Comment: We did this. We see the disconnection but not the reason. Our server sends a RST,ACK packet. There are many retransmissions.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something else but this smells like an issue with the TCP checksum. This function is often offloaded to the hardware card and you will not even be able to see the problem in Wireshark from the same machine (although it is usually obvious when you see it from a firewall dump).

If the checksum in the TCP packet is incorrect, it will cause the packet to be re-requested. If, after some time, one of the connected parties cannot build a properly validated window, it will consider the connection as broken and send a RSET packet.

So, have you tried disabling TCP offloading on your NIC ?

Comment: I could, but if the NIC is defective I want the provider to replace my server. When I have TCP connections from server to my client PC, I do not see CRC errors on Wireshark running on my PC. Is this a good test for CRC?

Comment: Yes, if you're connected to the server directly (no proxy but a firewall should be OK), and assuming you have disabled any hardware TCP offload on your own card (if it applies), you should see the checksum errors in wireshark.